# Build tools - why so many versions?

Tags: android

Every time I've updated the SDK and Android build environment I've got a new version of the build tools and rather than overwriting the previous version, as with most components, it creates a new directory in build-tools.

Thus I have directories: 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 18.0.1. ( I missed out on 18.1.1 somehow, even though the SDK manager says it's available). I did have 19.0.0 when I upgraded to API19 but hit the same problems as in this question: [Android Dex gives a BufferOverflowException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception) I uninstalled 19.0.0 and could build my previously working apps again.

What's it all about? Why the separate folders rather than overwriting? Why don't build tools 19.0.0 work in Windows?

I'd very much appreciate it if anyone could enlighten me here.

Comment: I believe that you have answered your own question.  If it just overwrote, how would you recover from the problem you encountered?  Good versioning practice includes the tool chain.

Comment: @Simon, well maybe, but none of the other components do it. That's why I always take a copy of the whole SDK before updating!

Comment: Platforms, SDKs and build tools do.  That's everything needed in the build process.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Android builds should never break when you update your sdk. To make sure it never breaks, you need to be able to build with any version of the build tools. That's why there are separate. 
If you don't like it and you only want to latest one, you can remove the old ones from your pc.