# How do I remove duplicate libraries appearing in Eclipse /bin/dexedLibs folder for Android dev?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've seen this error reported several times, but none of the solutions I have read seem to help me.  I'm getting the following error:

```
Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/annotation/SuppressLint;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/annotation/SuppressLint;
```

I did some digging around and I'm seeing these jar files in the /bin/dexedLibs folder:

```
android-support-v4-198bc014c99a20da45e22ed9cbf6acfc.jar
annotations-548f83e84eb7d75caedbdd94af586669.jar
annotations-c206a845ecee15ca74bd8ea29f715ccd.jar
google-play-services-90fd245eca6bf1f2b0d2bb25ec3948cc.jar
google-play-services_lib-6007bc6f3ac755b4866fa4a11c4e1704.jar
guice-3.0-no_aop-12e0ac277316bccd821359aa41181ed8.jar
javax.inject-384e1baadfa688e537ac642df7b9e932.jar
jsr305-1.3.9-13c6c964842f2bc7643c588e6fdc4754.jar
ormlite-android-4.47-185a20bcc9d996b5de6d6ca2aff0d0d5.jar
ormlite-core-4.47-42acd47179ed45763a3ec81ac92a2f20.jar
roboguice-2.0-f9de91c4687c33313255e5dd6fd324b3.jar
simple-xml-2.7.1-d80fa5a8427ec77885976924091eb340.jar
teklibrary-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-cd7381a5468da36c532837d7604e95b3.jar
```

See the duplicate `annotations` and `google_play_services` jar files.  This is what my eclipse looks like.  I don't know how `Google Play Services` and `Annotations` are appearing in both `Android Private Libraries` and `Android Dependencies`.

[image]

This is where my `Google Play Services` is getting added to the project. The reason I have it added that way was due to an issue with the following line in code in AndroidManifest.xml where `@integer/google_play_services_version` wasn't being recognized.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

[image]

In Project Properties | Java Build Path | Order and Export, I have unchecked `Android Dependencies`.

[image]

---

**So the question, anyone know how to resolve this issue:**

```
[2013-11-29 10:30:49 - TekJobsAppAndroid2] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2013-11-29 10:30:49 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/annotation/SuppressLint;
[2013-11-29 10:30:49 - TekJobsAppAndroid2] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/annotation/SuppressLint;
```

Thanks in advance

Please note that I consistently do the following:

- Delete the contents of the BIN folder
- Clean Project
- Build Project

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: clean project and if it still fails, see what happens if you remove the annotations.jar from the libs folder.

Comment: I removed the annotations.jar and now I'm getting 'Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.' error.  Put the lib back in and error won't go away.  Deleted the bin folder, cleaned the project and no go. I saw this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception which might resolve it, but need to find that version of the tool.

Answer (score 1):

Open Java Build Path ->Open Libraries Tab-> Expand all ->Find Duplicate -> Remove Them.

Delete Bin Folder.
Clean Project

Comment: I deleted Android Dependencies (didn't know I was allowed), deleted the BIN folder and Clean Project with no change.

Comment: What all jar files are you using ?

Comment: Dude you have two annotations.jar and two google-play-services jar. Remove duplicates. That is why this error is coming

Comment: I know that, should have mentioned it above.  I don't know why I had the duplicates, but deleting Android Dependencies took care of that. But now I have another error. 'Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741758/bufferoverflowexception-when-building-application