# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Tags: android

I am getting following exception when I am trying to run my Android project.

**Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException**

Currently now I am using ADT version 22.3. My project target is API level-15. I tried to add Support library in Android tools, but problem not resolved.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741758/bufferoverflowexception-when-building-application/19761843#19761843

Comment: How can i uninstall Build- 19

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building

Comment: clean project. Did you use Android libraries? Maybe they use support library (it can be problem with redudant libraries)

Comment: Thanks Gopal Rao.. Problem solved.. :)

Comment: I was having redundant libraries in my IDE that was causing an issue

Answer (score 47):

the key is to set `target=android-19` from `project.properties` and `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` same to 19. This has worked for me.

Comment: Just to make it clear for viewers, this is the solution which worked upon first attempt. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Its a big mess... Following way did the trick for me...

> Right click your project in eclipse -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library

Then click `Accept License` and click `install`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I used these methods

1- Downgrading to Android SDK build tools 18.1.1

2- Adding the support library. (if it already there, try removing it and adding it again, Right click on project -> Android tools -> Add support library)

you can follow the detailed instructions here
http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/how-to-solve-unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-for-stack-trace/

Comment: Step 1 fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

Link above is broken but provides valid solution. Updated link: http://techlovejump.in/how-to-solve-unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-for-stack-trace/

Answer (score 2):

Is this the same problem as [Android dex gives a BufferOverflowException when building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building) ? Updating to the 19.0.1 Build-tools (as described in the linked post) fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Browse through your eclipse Folder->
Open Eclipse Folder
Open eclipse.ini
Change  **-Xms40m  And  -Xmx384m  TO -Xms512m  And  -Xmx512m**

Click Save

Comment: I had to change them to 1024

Answer (score 0):

No need to downgrade.
You can fix the error by editing the manifest file or project properties. Add following line.

```
sdk.build.tools=18.1.1
```

replace 18.1.1 with your targetsdk in manifest.

Step by step detail on :- http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/how-to-solve-unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-for-stack-trace/

Answer (score 0):

I Update the project.properties file. I put  sdk.build.tools=19.0.1 in property file. And set the minimum SDK version to 14

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me when my emulator had set a high Ram value, i changed the emulator RAM value to 768 and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this problem when using Sherlock ActionBar library in my project.
You could do the following step, it's work for me.

1. Right click to your project, select properties.
2. A dialog will show up, select 'Java build path' on the left menu.
3. Remove 'Android dependencies' and 'Android private libraries' on the right panel then click OK
4. Clean your project (select menu Project --> Clean)
5. Right click your project, select Android Tools -> Fix project properties
6. Clean project once again.
7. Restart your computer
8. Open eclipse and Export apk

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having redundant libraries in my IDE that was causing an issue none of the other solution worked for me