# What might cause java.nio.BufferOverflowException?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to run the code at https://github.com/kpbird/chipsedittext out-of-the-box and get the following error

```
Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2014-03-25 11:24:58 - ChipsEditTextActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building

Answer (score 0):

[BufferOverflowException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/BufferOverflowException.html)

> Unchecked exception thrown when a relative put operation reaches the
>   target buffer's limit.

As the name say, it's thrown when the buffer reach the max size.

I found this question which should help you

- [Android dex gives a BufferOverflowException when building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building)
- [BufferOverflowException when building application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741758/bufferoverflowexception-when-building-application)