# Error when running Android app

Tags: eclipse-adt

After I updated to ADT 22.3 i get this error:

```
[2013-11-09 17:56:27 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2013-11-09 17:56:27 - Chinese Notecards] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

What do I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Dex gives a BufferOverflowException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

Right click your Project > Android tools > Add support library

Also check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61710

Answer (score 8):

Try removing the **Android Dependencies** from your project, in addition to the above suggestions.

Steps:

1. Right Click on your project -> **Build Path** -> **Configure Build Path...**
2. Remove Android Dependencies from the Libraries tab.

This worked in my case, but removing the **Android Dependencies** may introduce errors in your project. So, be sure to review the project dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Try right click your project > android > Project build Target >select less version than 4.4
and try to clean the project.

It worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

right click your project > android > Project build Target >select less version than 4.4

Also check Make sure that the value of android:targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml matches target=android- in project.properties. If these two values are not the same, building with build tools version 19.0.0 will end in the BufferOverflowException. After That Clean Project it works for me :)