# How to solve this java.nio.BufferOverflowException error?

Tags: android, eclipse

When i tried to compile my code in eclipse with ADT,  it showed me this error

```
[2013-12-10 17:55:51 - Android SDK] Warning when loading the SDK:

Warning: Ignoring build-tool 'add-ons': missing file source.properties
[2013-12-10 18:02:33 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2013-12-10 18:02:33 - Nasa Daily Image] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

Why am I getting this error message ?

How to solve that error ?

Comment: Checkout below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741758/bufferoverflowexception-when-building-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885061/error-when-running-android-app

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the value of android:targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml matches target=android- in project.properties. If these two values are not the same, building with build tools version 19.0.0 will end in the BufferOverflowException, check the mentioned links if you http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/how-to-solve-unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-for-stack-trace/

Answer (score 0):

I have got that same issue and i changed the project Build Target from Android 2.2(API Level 8) to Android  4.2.2(API Level 17).
My target and min SDK version is still 8.
It worked for me.