# android project error when run it,it's API level is 11

Tags: android

my android project with problem fololowed:
`Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.`
It said that is Android packaging problem,but I can not find where have problem with my project.

Comment: Your error is saying - Check the log for stack trace. G oto your logcat view and paste the error here

Answer (score 0):

I hava meet the same question, but when I change a different build target version and clean the whole project, this erroe disappeared.

Try to click Project-->properties-->Android-->choose a different build target, and Project-->Clean-->check your project and clean it.

Otherwise I find the same question here:[Android dex gives a BufferOverflowException when building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception). If my advice doesn't work, try to uninstall build tools 19 and revert build tools to 18.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: yes right . that is build tools bug / so you can just   revert tools to 18.1.1 and !!! reboot the  eclipse .

Comment: but when I clean my project, I lost my R.java.

Comment: R.java is auto generated, if you check build automatically, it will appear after clean project. Try to manually click project-->build project?