# Eclipse buffer overflow Google Glass

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, google-glass, google-gdk

I have seen all of the other buffer overflow posts and I have tried everything they have said. The thing is I am not on API 19 like most people getting the error are. I am building glassware for Google Glass so I am on API 15 (4.0.3). Why would I be getting this error?

```
[(timestamp) Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[(timestamp) - (AppName)] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with the API version of Android that you're compiling against, but with the version of the Android build tools that you have installed. Please see the resolutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292212/how-to-launch-a-regular-activity-on-google-glass), which should help you.