# Glassware build errors with ADT on Mac ; project crashes in Console before running

Tags: adt, google-glass, eclipse-adt

Whenever I try to run my glass app I get these weird errors in the console after I run my Glassware project onto Glass Hardware:
 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
 - $myproject] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

Note: ($myproject is the name of my project)

Anyone know how to fix these?  I find it really really really hard to use ADT compared to Xcode.  Where is a good resource to get familiar with ADT and get answers on ADT dev environment for Glass?

Comment: While you are awaiting a solution to your chosen method of loading, you may want to consider using the ChromeADB extension to the Chrome Browser (look in the Chrome Web Store .. thanks BrickSimple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please post what Build Tools and SDK versions you are using on the current project?

You need Android SDK Build Tools **19.0.1** and Android SDK needs **4.0.3** which are not the most current releases. In order to Install these, use SDK Manager.

See this StackOverflow post with similar error message.

[How to launch a regular activity on google glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292212/how-to-launch-a-regular-activity-on-google-glass)

Comment: I fixed the problem by essentially running through each SO post on Glass dev environment debugging, cleaning my project, and restarting ADT a dozen times.  It was just 3 hours of annoying configuration frustration until the Glass app built with ADT and runs on device.