# Error starting app from eclipse with SDK Tools 19

Tags: android, sdk

I get the following error when try to start my App from eclipse with API Level 15 after upgrading to SDK Revision 19 :

> [Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException.
>   Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

With API Level 16 it works. With API Level 15 it doesn't work. I would like to use Level 15.

I tried so far 'Add Support Library' as suggested in StackOverflow.

In my Manifest :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building/19803777#19803777 use this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when the builder is different than the `targetSdkVersion`

In your manifest file write

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

And it should work, and do this every time you upgrade the sdk version. Verify that the sdk matches the `targetSdkVersion` of your app.