# Android dex gives a BufferOverflowException on build, when targetting API 8

Tags: android

I am running on command-line only. I have tried the various fixes suggested by different stackoverflow answers (adding the Android support library, setting `project.properties` to use `18.1.1`, but none of them seem to fix the problem. I have tried with both version `19` and version `18.1.1` of the `platform-tools`.

Here is the output of `android list targets`

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-8"
     Name: Android 2.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 8
     Revision: 3
     Skins: WQVGA432, QVGA, WVGA854, WQVGA400, WVGA800 (default), HVGA
     ABIs : armeabi
----------
id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:8"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 2
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 2.2 (API level 8)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WQVGA400, WVGA854, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), QVGA
     ABIs : armeabi
----------
id: 3 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 1
     Skins: WQVGA432, QVGA, WVGA854, WXGA720, WSVGA, WXGA800, WQVGA400, WVGA800 (default), HVGA, WXGA800-7in
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 4 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.4 (API level 19)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WQVGA400, WVGA854, WSVGA, WXGA800-7in, WXGA720, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WXGA800
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
```

Here is the command I am using the create the project:

```
android create project \
--target 1 \
--name Foo \
--path Foo \
--activity Foo \
--package  com.Foo
```

When I `cd` into the directory, and use `ant build`, I immediately get the `BufferOverflowException` described in the other questions:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:519)
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putShort(HeapByteBuffer.java:315)
        at com.android.dex.Dex$Section.writeShort(Dex.java:818)
        at com.android.dex.Dex$Section.writeTypeList(Dex.java:870)
```

Note that, I also ran `adb -verbose debug`, and the actual command that breaks is this (directories removed):

```
│'<android_home>/build-tools/19.0.0/dx'
│with arguments:
│       [dx] '--dex'
│       [dx] '--output'
│       [dx] '/<path>/Foo/bin/classes.dex'
│       [dx] '/<path>/Foo/bin/classes'
│       [dx] '/<path>/Foo/bin/dexedLibs/annotations-064aab7f6d582a07d494f
│b587176a0bd.jar'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building)  was counterproductive for me. Simply removing the revision `19` of the `Build-tools` was the only way I found which solved the problem.

It may be a problem that is specific to `API 8`, although I did not test with higher `API 9`.