# PhoneGap - Android build throws error - BUILD FAILED - \ant\build.xml:892

Tags: android, cordova

When I try to build Android platform, I was getting the below error and when I searched for fix found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building) and tried the same by downloading different build tools but it didn't worked out and later after two days it worked normally (not sure how it was) and I was able to execute the build and again in sometime I am getting the same error.

Using PhoneGap 3.3.0

```
>phonegap build android
   [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
   [phonegap] using the local environment
   [phonegap] compiling Android...
   [error] An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "C:\dev\phonegap\web-service\platforms\android\build.xml"": BUILD FAILED
   C:\dev\tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:
   C:\dev\tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
   C:\dev\tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:906: The following error occurred while executing this line:
   C:\dev\tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:284: null returned: 1

   Total time: 7 seconds
```

Rarely below error:

```
>phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[error] An error occurred while building the android project.
```

If I run the build command again it throws the first error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your android SDK location assign correctly in local.properties file.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Applications/android-sdk
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply, yes the android SDK location is assigned correctly

`sdk.dir=C:\\dev\\tools\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\\sdk`

No idea what is wrong.

Comment: But sometimes restarting the system solves the issue, I wonder how! :(

Comment: so your problem fixed?