# Android LockScreen

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I am planning to create a Android Lock Screen of my own .
But i don't know where to start?
Should i just make an activity with UI layout that interacts touches, and when the user swipes I should call the `androd.intent.HOME` ?

And how can i override the default android Lock Screen application?

I really dont have a clue any help would be appreciated.
I saw this post : [Where can I find examples or tutorials about creating a custom android lockscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983143/where-can-i-find-examples-or-tutorials-about-creating-a-custom-android-lockscree/7983935#7983935)
but its not very helpful

And my device is rooted and i dont mind making the app only for ROOTED users..

Comment: you can refer this - https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp

Comment: well as much as i hate using github on my windows :P ,
Cloning the repo ..
Will try it .. thanks

Comment: well i cannot build it .. getting this error "conversion to dalvik format failed unable to execute dex" .. and i cant rectify it with the help of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087341/multiple-dex-files-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex)
As i dont have the jar files , so i wont be able to reimport them after deleting .. (As suggested in the answer of the question on the uppermentioned link)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Lock Screen Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget)

Comment: @Andru this question is about creating a lockscreen. Not creating a widget on lock screen

Comment: @MihirSolanki did you reach something about that?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Nope :( I dun seem to find anything

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few weeks ago exactly the same thing.
I came to the conclusion that you cannot *easily* change the lockscreen.

IMO currently the *easiest* (It doesn't mean it's actually easy) method to do it, is to use the Xposed Framework.

[Check out this Link](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial)

It will give you a brief overview how to hook and intercept methods.

You could search & hook the method which opens the LockScreen and launch your own...

Good Luck :)

Comment: Well i am aware about the framework but then for the most part, i will have to make app for specific devices like for Samsung touchwiz or AOSP like CyanogenMod.. I won't be able to create something that works with all android device.. Kindoff demotivats me to create a lockscreen.

Comment: Yeah. I know what you mean. I also gave up on a custom lockscreen for the same reason :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no lock screen tutorial.
Still google not provided any api for custom lockscreen.
You need to write your own home screen app which will implement the lockscreen behaviour that you require. There is sample code for writing your own home screen app in the Android SDK(Source code).